# Correct analyzer for a field with backslash

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

So, I'm trying to setup a new index mapping with the correct analyzer for a Windows credential field, which has the format `domain\username`.

I want to be able to search for domain, username AND domain\username. But the default analyzer seems to ignore the backslash (meaning, if I try to search for domain\username it will search for "domain OR username" ignoring the backslash), and if I try the whitespace analyzer it seems to only match on domain\username.

Any tips?

Comment: Can you add your query

Comment: sorry, jaspreet, it wasn't actually about making a query, but about building an index ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the path hierarchy tokenizer, setting the backslash as delimiter - doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html)
Try:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_path_tree": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_hierarchy"
        },
        "custom_path_tree_reversed": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_hierarchy_reversed"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "custom_hierarchy": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": "\"
        },
        "custom_hierarchy_reversed": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": "\",
          "reverse": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "file_path": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "tree": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "custom_path_tree"
          },
          "tree_reversed": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "custom_path_tree_reversed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "custom_path_tree",
  "text": "C:\Windows\Users"
}
```

Comment: Ooooohhhh I can't wait too test it, this seems like it'll work perfectly!!

Comment: please have a look to the examples page https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer-examples.html

Comment: hm... no luck. When I try to search for "domain\username" it returns the correct domain, but seems to not look for the username. And then, if I try to search for a specific username, nothing is returned =(

Comment: ah ok, look at the examples in my previuos comment, you should set the reverse param to true. I will update my answer